# ImageView must be used from main thread only

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uiimageview, uiimage

I am getting a url from my firebase database to be download images and am getting this error on the cell.articleImage.image = UIImage(data: data) in the main thread, It is not crashing but it won't return the images, anyone know what could be going wrong?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let v = UIView(frame: .zero)
        }

    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleCell") as? articlesCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()}

        let article = articleArray[indexPath.row]

        let url = URL(string: article.imageURL)!
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            do{
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                DispatchQueue.global().sync {
                    cell.articleImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            } catch {

            }
        }



       // cell.articleImage.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "issaimage"))
        cell.configureCell(title: article.ArticleTitle, author: article.author, date: article.date)

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do it in global instead of main queue so change this

```
DispatchQueue.global().sync {
      cell.articleImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```

to

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync {
       cell.articleImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```

//

Again [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) is the best for that , as with this approach the image will be downloaded every scroll

//

Also in your `viewDidLoad`

```
DispatchQueue.global().async { // should be in main queue 
   let v = UIView(frame: .zero)  // whatever UI is here 
}
```

Comment: its just returning blank image

Comment: then the problem with your url , copy an internet image url , hardcode it , then check

Comment: twas an issue with the url, thanks for all the help you've given me

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
func openImageGallery() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.allowsEditing = true
        self.picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(self.picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```